# Which function is invoked on click of notification while flutter android app is in terminated state, background notification click FCM

Tags: flutter, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, terminate, localnotification

I am using flutter_local_notifications: ^15.1.0+1 to show notification using FCM.
i was able to handle notification click on foreground and background clicks , But i couldn't find a function which is invoked on notification tap while the app is in terminated state.
Any help will be welcomed .

`onDidReceiveNotificationResponse` is invoked while app is in background or foreground,
Using custom notification with local_notification package,
below is my FCM content

```
 { "message":{
      "token":"token_1",
      "data":{
        "title":"FCM Message",
        "body":"This is an FCM notification message!",
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

`flutter_local_notifications` will handle incoming message in the `foreground` notification. because the `Firebase Android SDK` will block displaying any FCM notification no matter what Notification Channel has been set.

read here for detail: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/notifications#application-in-foreground

---

while on `teminated` state, no need to use local notification. if you still use `flutter_local_notification` to handle `background` state, you will receive 2 notifications at the same time.

for handling received message read this documentation:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive

---

- invoke method everytime revice notification

you can call your method here, it will automatically invoked if the notification incomming in the terminated state

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  // If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,
  // make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
 /// call you method here <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
}

void main() {
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

but if you need interaction, for example, you want to navigate specific screen when user click the notification in the `terminated state, then read below:

- interaction

by default, when we click the notification, it will trigger to open the app.
based on my project, I use invoke my method on the `splash screen` before navigate to home screen.

`splash_screen.dart`

```
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setupInteractedMessage();
  }


 Future<void> setupInteractedMessage() async {
    // Get any messages which caused the application to open from
    // a terminated state.
    RemoteMessage? initialMessage =
        await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();

    // If the message also contains a data property with a "type" of "chat",
    // navigate to a chat screen
    if (initialMessage != null) {
      _handleMessage(initialMessage);
    }

    // Also handle any interaction when the app is in the background via a
    // Stream listener
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(_handleMessage);
  }

 void _handleMessage(RemoteMessage message) {
    /// Navigate to detail
    String notifType = message.data['type'] ?? '';
      if (notifType == "chatiii"){
          // navigate to specific screen
          Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => const ChatScreen()),
            (Route<dynamic> route) => true);
   }
 }
...

}
```

Comment: i don't have "notification" field and FCM notification content is like this  and using custom notification in all app states {
   "message":{
      "token":"token_1",
            "data":{
        "title":"FCM Message",
        "body":"This is an FCM notification message!",
      }}
      After trying with await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage(); its returning null all the time its not working in my case .